# Google Container Engine StatefulSets in kubernetes 1.5.1 don't seem to work

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have been waiting to use the StatefulSet functionality from GCE for a while. Their docs claim that it's now available in 1.5.1 but it doesn't seem to work at all.

From what I can tell the apps/v1alpha1 api still exists but PetSet is no longer there but the apps/v1beta1 that houses StatefulSet is not enabled.

The docs say that it is, but it's not.

> PetSet's name has changed to StatefulSet in version 1.5. StatefulSet
>   is a beta feature available in regular Container Engine clusters, and
>   PetSet is no longer available in Alpha Clusters.

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters

and here's the error I get when I try to use a StatefulSet in apps/v1beta1 as per the kubernetes docs. (it also fails using apps/v1alpha1 as does a PetSet in apps/v1alpha1)

> API version "apps/v1beta1" isn't supported, only supports API versions
>   ["apps/v1alpha1" "componentconfig/v1alpha1" "v1"
>   "authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" "authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
>   "autoscaling/v1" "batch/v1" "batch/v2alpha1"
>   "certificates.k8s.io/v1alpha1" "extensions/v1beta1" "policy/v1alpha1"
>   "federation/v1beta1" "storage.k8s.io/v1beta1"
>   "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1"]; if you choose to ignore these
>   errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Am I reading this correctly as they never enabled the StatefulSet functionality for kubernetes 1.5.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very likely you have mismatching versions of Kubernetes running on the client and the server. I discovered something similar, due to a quirk of the `gcloud` `kubectl`-installation, namely it, despite updating, still running on `1.4.x`. Run `kubectl version` and update the binary for your platform manually.

You need `1.5+` on both ends.